# Roblox Lua - attempt to index nil with 'stats' (leaderstats)

Tags: lua, roblox

i want to make this, when the baseFinal is touched by a block (Bloque) it gives you money and the block is destroyed. it gives me an error: attempt to index nil with 'stats'

```
local base = script.Parent.Base

local baseFinal = script.Parent.Final

local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer


baseFinal.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    
    if hit.Name == "Bloque" then
        wait(0.6)
        plr.stats.Value = plr.stats.Value + 5  // here is the error
        hit:Destroy()
    end
     
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the `plr` variable is undefined or nil.

Since this code is running in a Script, the issue is how you are accessing the Player object. See the documentation for [Players.LocalPlayer](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer) :

> This property is only defined for LocalScripts (and ModuleScripts required by them), as they run on the client. For the server (on which Script objects run their code), this property is nil.

The way to fix this is to access the Player object another way. One way is to connect to the Players.PlayerAdded signal.

```
local base = script.Parent.Base
local baseFinal = script.Parent.Final

local connections = {}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect( function(plr)
    -- listen for Players to touch the block
    local connection = baseFinal.Touched:Connect( function(hit)
        if hit.Name == "Bloque" then
            wait(0.6)
            plr.stats.Money.Value = plr.stats.Money.Value + 5
            hit:Destroy()
        end
    end)

    -- hold onto the connection to clean it up later
    connections[plr] = connection
end)

-- clean up when the Player leaves
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect( function(plr)
    connections[plr]:Disconnect()
end)
```

Comment: And also replace `plr.stats.Value` with `plr.stats.Money.Value`

Comment: I thank you very much, the only problem I have is that the money is not seen in the leaderboards but the most complicated thing is solved and I can continue progressing

Comment: I just realized that this code will give ALL players 5 money anytime a "Bloque" object touches the base. This may not be what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because when you are trying to reference a value, you must put `.Value` after it in order to change the value itself. Assuming you have a stats folder, you should use `plr.stats.Value.Value` instead.
Next time, please show us your object structure so we have a better understanding of what the error is. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The only problem is that I didn't mean that. The error keeps happening. It keeps saying:  Workspace.GeneradorBloques-Tycoon1.GeneradorBloque.Base.Script:11: attempt to index nil with 'stats'

Here is a picture of the Workspace and the location of the stats folder: [link](https://imgur.com/a/9gJaLZp)

Comment: Can I see the structure of the stats folder?

Comment: Here you have: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Rw2C9JN)

Comment: The issue is that you are referencing the value in the script as `Value` instead of by its name which is `Money`. Try `plr.stats.Money.Value = plr.stats.Money.Value + 5`

Comment: I'm an idiot. I just realized that this is running in a regular script instead of a LocalScript. refer to Kylaaa's answer for the syntax and use `plr.stats.Money.Value` to reference it. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: I thank you anyway! Not being ignored also helps me feel like continuing to work on my game.

Comment: I'm really glad. As a roblox dev myself my biggest obstacle is motivation and I hope you continue to work on your game. When it's done by all means please post a link here and I'll try it <3